# Karma Tesing on Virtual Machine

Tags: javascript, tfs, virtual-machine, karma-jasmine, headless-browser

I am trying to run karma tests as part of an automated TFS build. The build opens a browser window and fails to run headless on the build server. What is the best browser configuration for this scenario? 
Thanks!

the package.json script is

```
"headlessTest":"karma start --browsers ChromeHeadless karma.conf.js"
```

```js
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

output in console window in TFS build

`[33m01 08 2017 10:03:00.043:WARN [launcher]: [39mChromeHeadless have not` `captured in 60000 ms, killing.`
`[33m01 08 2017 10:03:02.087:WARN [launcher]: [39mChromeHeadless was not` `killed in 2000 ms, sending SIGKILL.`
``` [33m01 08 2017 10:03:04.208:WARN [launcher]: [39mChromeHeadless was not``killed by SIGKILL in 2000 ms, continuing. ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try lunching the chrome with "nosandbox".

Use following configuration in your karma `project.conf.js`:

```
browsers: ['ChromeNoSandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
        ChromeNoSandbox: {
            base: 'Chrome',
            flags: ['--no-sandbox']
        }
    }
```

Reference this Github issue: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/73#issuecomment-236597429

---

**UPDATE:**

There is an issue for Karma : [github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/2652](http://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/2652) , whatever you can try different versions combination for Karma and Chrome, someone mentioned that [downgrading to karma 1.5](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/2652#issuecomment-293236553) worked.

You can also try to increase the Timeout value, eg 600000, then try it again.

Comment: OK so i did that but am still getting a timeout error on the tfs console `INFO [karma]: [39mKarma v1.7.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9877/
 [launcher]: [39mLaunching browser ChromeNoSandbox with unlimited concurrency
INFO [launcher]: [39mStarting browser Chrome

[33m02 08 2017 10:25:31.770:WARN [launcher]: [39mChrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
WARN [launcher]: [39mChrome was not killed in 2000 ms, sending SIGKILL.
:WARN [launcher]: [39mChrome was not killed by SIGKILL in 2000 ms, continuing.`

Comment: @ProfessorMoriarty Seems there is an issue for Karma https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/2652, whatever you can try different versions combination for Karma and Chrome, someone mentioned that [downgrading to karma 1.5](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/2652#issuecomment-293236553) worked